# Azure Sql Server VM Recycle

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

When a Sql Server VM (IaaS VM) is recycled (for whatever reason, hardware failure, etc) and comes up on a different VM) can my app continue using the database (once the new VM comes up) automatically or do I manually have to restore the database? Do I manually have to attach the disks again? Even if the disks are attached automatically, will the database restore also happen automatically? If the disks are available automatically, will my data files also be present on the new VM?

Answer (score 1):

In case of a hardware failure, the experience to the guest O/S - your SQL Server VM - would be as if someone had pulled the power cord and restarted the server. configuration of the VM will remain the same, including all attached disks etc. but operations that were not yet persisted to disk may have been lost. the impact depends on how you use the server in terms of transactions etc.

I believe that scheduled maintenance is a bit more organised and the VM will be shut down in an orderly fashion increasing the consistency for your application.

Comment: Thanks Yossi for the response. So I take it there is no need for me to write some sort of startup script to attach databases, etc. My original database will be present in the new VM, The attached disks would still contain my data and log file. My app can continue connecting to the database and there is no manual intervention required. Request you to confirm, will mark this as answer once you confirm. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, typically how long does it take for a SQL Server 2012 VM to be active once it is recycled?

Comment: I believe so. Once again - you need to consider the impact on your application and data of the database server disappearing abruptly, but you don't need to re-create the VM from scratch.

Comment: We usually see 15-20 minutes, but it can take more. I've seen it take an hour at times. I don't believe there are firm commitments from Microsoft on that.

Comment: You're talking about having a single-instance VM for a database and you're asking what would happen if the VM is recycled - if this is planned maintenance the server would be shut down. If this is a hardware failure it will potentially simply 'crash'. In either case it will be back, but you client application will have lost the database for a bit of time, potentially mid-transaction. You will need to cater for that. Nothing special to do with Azure. Would be the case for on-perm servers in the same way.

Comment: Thanks Yossi. This answers my question. Any way I can simulate a recycle in Azure for a SQL VM?